# Best way to authorize a USB device in an organisation?

Tags: usb, security, software-rec, usb-storage, secure-desktop

I am developing a project where I need to restrict usage of accessing non white-listed USB devices in the organization's network.

I am using it by checking the VID and PID of that USB devices.

Now, the problem is that if I have, for example, an **Apple I-pad**, that would have a global VID and PID number. If I white list any of the Apple I-Pads then, with my current scenario, all other Apple I-Pads would be authorized in the network.

Is using VID and PID numbers the best way to check if a USB device is white-listed, or is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind this isn't going to prevent people from booting via USB unless you disable "Boot from USB" in BIOS of each computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at this document :
[Thumb Drive Threats and Countermeasures in a Microsoft Windows](http://www.giac.org/paper/gsec/4104/thumb-drive-threats-countermeasures-mircosoft-windows-environment/106563)

Especially look at the chapter "Threat Countermeasures", where are described the security measures
built into Windows, as well as commercial security products such as :

[GFI LanGuard](http://www.gfi.com/network-security-vulnerability-scanner/lanscanfeatures.htm)
[Lumension](http://www.lumension.com/)
[DeviceLock](http://www.devicelock.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the information, but have you worked on any such kind of security measures in any organisation?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with any of these products. Employees in my company can take home their laptops, so thumb drives are not our main worry.

Answer (score 2):

Most USB devices with storage have a serial number; use that.

For example, in Linux, you can see this in the output of `lsusb`:

```
lsusb -v
...
Device Descriptor:
  ...
  idVendor 0x1908
  idProduct 0x0102
  ...
  iManufacturer 2 BUILDWIN
  iProduct 3 Digital Photo Frame
  iSerial 1 200807101900000000
  ...
```

Comment: Can you show any serial number example here

Comment: I am using Asp.net c#, and does not found any Serial Number.

Comment: On Windows, you get the VID, PID and serial# from the device InstanceID.

Comment: serial id is what device id you are talking about.?correct me if i am wrong

Comment: This page looks as if it might help you: [How to Access the Serial Number on Your Flash Drive](http://www.customusb.com/blog/how-to-access-the-serial-number-on-your-flash-drive/)